# How to make BackSpace act like normal in textchanged event?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form which has three textboxes  namely-id,name, address.

On using textchanged event on id,  When i type id( 1,2,3,...),name and address field is automatically populated from database. I did this but when i press backspace,the visual studio fires exception.

**when i press backspace, i want it to act like normal backspace.How can i acheive this?**

Plz help me.

```
void showData1()
{
    con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=lakhe-pc;Initial Catalog=samplepractice;Integrated Security=True");
    con.Open();
    cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "spShowCustomer1";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("id", SqlDbType.Int);
    cmd.Parameters["id"].Value = txtId.Text;
    adap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    ds = new DataSet();
    adap.Fill(ds, "customer");
    txtName.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();
    txtAddress.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[1].ToString();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    con.Close();
}

private void txtId_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    try
    {
        showData1();
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Something unexpected happened.Please be patient.");
        txtId.Clear();
        txtName.Clear();
        txtAddress.Clear();
    }
    finally
    {           
    }
}
```

Comment: Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32.

Comment: And the exception is pointing to adap.Fill(ds, "customer");

Comment: Do exception occur at this line `cmd.Parameters["id"].Value = txtId.Text;`. If yes look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should not call the `showData1()` method when you text box is empty.

When you have `1` for example in your text box, and you press the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key, the text box becomes empty and the `TextChanged` event is raised. You should check for that situation:

```
private void txtId_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtId.Text))
        showData1();
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very very much sir.I have been trying to do this since yesterday.

Comment: @shrawan_lakhe You're welcome. Debugging is your friend. Use breakpoins and step through your code to find problems. Happy learning.

Answer (score 0):

Acc. to your exception

`Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32.`

I guess your problem is here

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("id", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd.Parameters["id"].Value = txtId.Text;
```

You are telling that the parameter is of type Int and providing a text value.

Instead try this (Don't forget to put some checks of String Null or Empty).

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("id", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd.Parameters["id"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtId.Text);
```